# Has Truffle's call() function stopped working as expected?

Tags: solidity, unittesting

I recently upgraded `ganache-cli` and many of my `truffle test`s stopped working. In particular, there were tests where I make a contract method invocation with `.call()` in order to get the return value instead of a transaction back.

For instance, with a method that creates a new thingy and returns the ID that was assigned to it, I used to invoke with '`call()`' to get the id back, expecting that no actual data would be persisted. Then I'd make the call 'for real' by not using `.call()`, and it would yield a transaction. The actual ID assigned would be the one that the invocation with `.call()` had returned.

My tests are now failing all over the place, and particularly, if I invoke a view function that returns the number of thingies that have been created the number is greater than expected. This is happening within the controlled environment of a unit test running against a local `ganache-cli` instance.

Can anyone confirm that `.call()` no longer works as expected and is actually creating data?

Comment: UPDATE: So, it appears that it isn't the call() function at all. I can run my tests one by one in isolation, and they pass. But If I just run the suite, most of them fail. It seems that the behavior that has stopped working as expected is that ```truffle test``` is not redeploying the contracts between tests.

Comment: Which version of truffle/ganache-cli are you using?

Comment: ivicaa - Ganache CLI v6.2.3 (ganache-core: 2.3.1), but that doesn't really matter, as the above update mentions, it seems that the problem is Truffle's test runner failing to redeploy / reset the contracts between test files.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you deploy your contracts will determine if Truffle re-deploys them for each test run. If they are deployed in the migration scripts eg `2_deploy_contracts.js` they will be deployed only once for your whole test suite. However, if you deploy them in a `beforeEach` function, [described here](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-hooks), inside the `contract` function in your test file then they should re-deploy for each run. Example from my code [here](https://github.com/willjgriff/solidity-playground/blob/master/Tokens/ERC223/test/StandardERC223TokenTest.js).

Also, consider emitting an [event](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#events) during the function that creates a new thingy, that includes the ID of the new thingy. You can then monitor for this or check the transaction receipt to get the ID rather than executing `.call()` before submitting a transaction.

Comment: This answer fixed my problem. For whatever reason, all my tests had been working fine when I used `const contract = await MyContract.deployed()` but suddenly that behavior had ceased. Now I'm using  `const contract = await MyContract.new()` and all's well.